# htaccess - redirect rule on directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directory

My site currently contains URL's like so:

```
mysite.com/accessories/bags
mysite.com/clothes/dresses
mysite.com/clothes/dresses/maxi
mysite.com/clothes/dresses/maxi/products
mysite.com/clothes/skirts
mysite.com/clothes/tops
mysite.com/clothes/tops/party
mysite.com/shoes
```

I now need to redirect any URL's that contain the `clothes` directory to another domain but keep the same structure.

Is there a rewrite rule where I can do something along the lines of:

```
mysite.com/clothes/* => newsite.com/clothes/*
```

i.e

```
mysite.com/clothes/dresses => newsite.com/clothes/dresses
mysite.com/clothes/dresses/maxi/products => newsite.com/clothes/dresses/maxi/products
```

And work for however many subfolders within `clothes`

I had been doing

```
redirect 301 /clothes/dresses https://www.newsite.com/clothes/dresses
```

But there are approx 2000 URL's with this instance so one rul to cover all would be good if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a simple `Redirect` directive

```
Redirect 301 /clothes/ https://www.example.com/clothes/
```

This will not just redirect `/clothes/` but also `/clothes/foobar` to `https://www.example.com/clothes/foobar` .